# How do I call stored procedures in EF Core 6 using named parameters with FromSqlRaw

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

I want to execute a stored procedure with a minimum of 3 to 20 parameters.
I am converting the property values from a request model to an SQL string and a list of parameters. Then make the call and expect a result but when I check the Created SQL from debug view, I observe that the EF tries to call the sp with non-named style parameters.

For brevity assume the first 3 properties contain values, and other properties have null values.

```
RequestModel 
{
   string Property1 { get; set; }
   string Property2 { get; set; }
   string Property3 { get; set; }
   ...
}

ResponseModel 
{
   string Response1 { get; set; }
   string Response2 { get; set; }
   ...
}

var sqlString = "exec sp_dummy @prop1, @prop2, @prop3";
var params = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@prop1", Property1),  new SqlParameter("@prop2", Property2),  new SqlParameter("@prop3", Propery3) };

return await ResponseModel.FromSqlRaw(sqlString, params).ToListAsync();
```

And when I check the generated SQL from EF Core, it is as follows:

```
DECLARE @prop1 nvarchar(10) = N'Prop1Data';
DECLARE @prop2 nvarchar(10) = N'Prop2Data';
DECLARE @prop3 nvarchar(10) = N'Prop3Data';

exec dummy_sp @prop1, @prop2, @prop3
```

What I want to achieve is as follows:

```
exec dummy_sp @prop1 = N'Prop1Data' , @prop2 = N'Prop2Data', @prop3 = N'Prop3Data'
```

Comment: Just use EF Core Power Tools

Comment: It calls it that way because you asked it to -- you supplied the statement. Use the syntax `exec dummy_sp @prop1 = @prop1, @prop2 = @prop2, @prop3 = @prop3` if you want to use named parameters (this looks redundant but isn't -- the first instance of each is the parameter name as declared by the sproc, the second is the parameter as passed to the RPC call to execute the statement, and they need not be the same). Mind you, this will still not get you that exact line of code, but that's by design -- parameters are not literals.

Comment: Incidentally, your output mentions `dummy_sp` but your code uses `sp_dummy`. Though this is an example, [do not use the `sp_` prefix for your procedures in production code](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix) -- it's reserved for system sprocs and has a small but measurable performance impact.

Comment: What you see in the trace may be only an approximation of what is sent to the server.  If the client uses an RPC call then there's really not a batch sent that looks like that.  Also why do you care which one it uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this by using dbcontext's ExecuteSqlRaw method, instead of FromSqlRaw extension method.

```
Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql,params);
```